# Geometry (Wax balls melted, Volume proportion) [CSIR June 2017]

Tags: geometry

> A tall metal cylinder is filled end-to-end with $n$ snugly fitting spherical wax balls of diameter $d$. If the balls melt completely, the volume fraction occupied by the melted wax is
>   a) independent of both $d$ and $n$
>   b) independent of $d$, but dependent of $n$
>   c) independent of $n$, but dependent of $d$
>   d) dependent on both $d$ and $n$

The correct Answer is a). But how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert $n-1$ circular discs of diameter $d=2r$ and thickness $0$ between the $n$ balls. Then each ball $B$ is enclosed in a cylindrical compartment $C$ of radius  $r$ and height $d$. One has
$${{\rm  vol}(B)\over{\rm vol}(C)}={{4\pi\over3} r^3\over\pi r^2\cdot 2r}={2\over3}\ ,$$
and this is also the fraction of  volume occupied by the wax at the end of the melting process, independently of $d$ and the number $n$ of balls.

Comment: But how did you assume the radius of the ball is same as that of the cylinder?@Christian Blatter

Comment: @cmi : That's how I interpreted "snugly fitting", together with the hint that answer a) should be correct.